# how to Integration or Configure On-premises SMTP Server with Jenkins? Email Extension Jenkins Plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins, smtp, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

***I have come across a scenario to integrate or configure On-premises SMTP Server with Jenkins.***

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of tutorial out there for popular mail service provider, you  but I did not find any for On-premises SMTP Server.

Note: This applies for Email Extension Jenkins Plugin only

Here is my Configuration,:

1.[Install Email Extension Jenkins Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/): Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Email Extension

2. Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Update the Extended E-mail Notification(expand by clicking on Advance option)
   Do not confuse with the another "E-mail Notification", this configuration is right below this.
   [image]

You may configure other options as per you requirements, I did not many other changes for testing.

3. Goto Pipeline Syntax -> Snippet Generator, copy generated snippet and use in your pipeline code.

[image]

4. Pipeline Example Code
   [image]

Hope this explanation works.  Good luck!